# WPF Multitrigger Can't be null

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, datagrid, multitrigger

This is my Multitrigger:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Dringlichkeit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Normal"/>
        <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Dringlichkeit, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Normal"/>
        <Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1"/>
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

If I use this trigger as a `DataTrigger`, the binding works.

But I need the `AlternationIndex`. I thought it was because I was loading the data via SQL, but when I load the style after SQL, I still have the problem that the binding has a `NULL` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation I can read that you should refer to your `AlterationIndex` like so:
`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}`
[MSDN Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.alternationindex(v=vs.110).aspx)
HTH

Comment: This is an approach, but I need in the binding the reference to the column "Dringlichkeit".
There is a value in the column "Dringlichkeit". With this value I would like to change the background color of the row.
All this under consideration of the AlternationIndex....

Comment: @D.Boden-Pollack you already have the reference in your MultiDataTrigger, all you need to do is to change your second `Condition` from `<Condition Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1"/>` to `<Condition Property="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}" Value="1"/>` if I understand you correctly.